# searching of common strings in two given input files

Tags: algorithm, bash, shell, awk

I have two files of size 20Gb each. I have to search common string among them. Assume Maximum length of strings are 20bytes. so to solve this i am using following algorithm I am using a system of 8GB RAM with quad core i3 CPU.

```
sort the files using any suitable sorting utility
open files A and B for reading
read wordA from A
read wordB from B
while (A not EOF and B not EOF)
{
    if (wordA < wordB)
        read wordA from A
    else if (wordA > wordB)
        read wordB from B
    else
        /* match found, store it into some other files */
        write wordA into output
        read wordA from A
}
```

it went successfully for above mentioned system configuration BUT when i run this algorithm in a system of 6Gb RAM and available disk space of 120GB with 6 cores i3 processor... my system got shut downed many times. Why this is happening?

Plz tell me any other way to solve this plm! Can we improve it performance?

Comment: pseudocode tells us nothing about your implementation

Comment: @Duck  "Segfault? Out of memory?" i am not getting it how it happened. Actually when i run this with 8Gb RAM it was using about 1.2GB RAM space and 0% swape space so i think it should also work with 6Gb RAM.But it didnt work why??

Comment: @MitchWheat yes sure it nothing say about implementation then how i can run the above algo with some other system configuration is there any other better logic that could run in any system?

Comment: @Gopal  I think '<' should be replaced by '=' in "if (wordA < wordB)"

Comment: @Gopal Also, which part is problematic? Here searching is more complicated and requires more juice. Were you able to simply sort the files without any problem?

Comment: @ElKamina "Here searching is more complicated" Can i use any other searching logic which wll be better than this? "Were you able to simply sort the files without any problem?" yes in some system everything went very well But in system(as above of 6Gb), it got shut downed during sorting ...

Comment: @Gopal So the problem IS sorting. Consider using merge sort. You might consider writing the code yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7181/discussion-between-gopal-and-elkamina)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can dramatically improve the performance using a very short `awk` 1-liner

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}a[$0]' file1 file2
```

With `awk` you can find unique lines without having to first sort them. You didn't really say what you wanted to do with common lines so I just assumed you wanted to print them out.

If you only want to print out a common line *once* no matter how many times it repeats you can use this:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1;next}a[$0]-- > 0' file1 file2
```

Comment: Ok it seemed well Can u clarify why and about how much it is better?

Comment: @Gopal I mentioned that you don't need to presort, so right there that is two full runs through the files removed from the task. How much better is only a question you can answer.